# How to group dates as custom week numbers in SQL?

Tags: sql, qlikview, qliksense

I have a series of email engagement dates, to create dashboard on QLIK. It has SQL Editor

I want to group a series of dates as Week 1, Week 2, and so on. My table has date column.

I am thinking along the lines for insert a column named "Week Number", based on the oldest date in the table, add 7 days range as week 1 and next 7 days range as Week 2 and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Qlik you can use the `weekstart(Date)` function or the `week(Date)` for just a week number. Either inthe script or as a calculated dimension in the chart.

Extra credit for `year(Date)&'-'&week(Date)` for 2019-23 etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use datepart(wk, date_column) for grouping by week. You may want to add datepart(yy, date_column) to group by year and week.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the first day in your table was which day of the week, and then use the following script in SQL Server

```
declare @FirstDayOfTableWeekDay int = 2

SELECT CEILING( (CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS float)+ CAST(@FirstDayOfTableWeekDay AS float)-1)  / 7) AS WeekNumber
FROM YourTable
```